# I don't see the "flag" link on posts?

Tags: support, site-usage

Is there a certain level you need to be at to have the ability to flag posts?
I looked at the FAQ and it shows the image illustrating how the flag link is next to edit and whatnot.  However, I don't see one on any questions/answers I look at.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Somehow, I knew you'd ask :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the FAQ:

[image: FAQ SS]

Comment: Oh boy.  I looked that list over a few times, I don't know how I missed that!  *blushing*  Thanks MDMama

Comment: Always listen to mama.

Comment: No freehand circles?!?

Comment: Freehand circles are too SO for me. I think SF should have jagged red arrows.

Comment: I missed that too... I even read that rep chart two or three times!